# Adding name and value to href

Tags: html

is it possible to add name and value to HTML a href Attribute? like similar example

`<p><a href="#">click here</a></p>`

Comment: Why you want that?

Comment: HTML5 doesn't support name attribute in a tag anymore. Prior to HTML5 you could use name attribute to give a name to anchor tag.

Comment: Values are for form elements like inputs, selects, etc. but not anchors. Look into custom data attributes

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
<a href="sample.php?(name)=(value)"> </a>
```

I usually do something like this, but I do not think it is the formal way.

Since I Use PHP, I sometimes make mine like this.

Ex. `<a href="sample.php?removeproduct=<?php echo $id;?>"> </a>`